# How do I access the link path of my video files on Android?

Tags: android, video

On my Desktop computer, I have a file "**test/video.html**" and "**test/myvid.mp4**" (video.html and myvid.mp4 are in the folder "**test**" in C: drive on my computer)

in the **video.html** file, I have

```
    callVideo (){
      video.src ='myvid.mp4'
      video.play();
    }
```

it works perfectly.

Now, I managed to copy **video.html** and **myvid.mp4** into **Downloads** folder on my Android device (I am using a **Lenovo Tablet**)

When I open my **Files** app   and go to "**Downloads**" folder and view the file info of **video.html** and "**myvid.mp4**", it shows "**storage/emulated/0/Download/video.html**" and "**storage/emulated/0/Download/myvid.mp4**" respectively.

When I doubleclick on "**storage/emulated/0/Download/video.html**", the webpage shows on my Chrome Browser. The webpage has all the buttons and links and so on but the page can not load the video **myvid.mp4**

I copied the address path of "**video.html**" on **Chrome**, it showed "**content://com.google.android.apps.nbu.files.provider/2/18718#**". It didn't show "**storage/emulated/0/Download/video.html**"

**How can I call my video from my video.html on my Android**?

**How do I get the link path of my video files on Android?**

Comment: Your observations are correct. The html file comes to you via the file provider of Files manager and obscures path. You better install a small webserver on your phone